# How to draw the graphic illustration for Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem (Cauchy's MVT)

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to insert the following graphic illustration for Cauchy's MVT in my lecture note.
[image]

I do not know how to make a loop and also to find the tangent at a specific point. Please help. The following code snippet is what I am using for Lagrange's MVT and I believe may serve as an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=3, yscale=2, >=stealth, declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x*\x+0.5; a=sqrt(0.37); g(\x)=f(a)+1.11*(\x-a); h(\x)=f(0)+1.11*(\x-0.1);}]
        \draw (0,0) -- (1.1,0);
        \draw [smooth, blue, domain=0.1:1, samples=10] plot(\x,{f(\x)});
        \draw [densely dashed, red, thick] (0,{h(0)}) -- (1.1,{h(1.1)});
        \draw [densely dashed] (0.1,0) node[below] {\scriptsize$ a $} -- (0.1,{f(0.1)});
        \draw [pen colour={white}, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, raise=1pt, amplitude=5pt}] (0.1,0) -- (0.1,{f(0.1)}) node[midway, left=5pt] {\scriptsize$ f(a) $};
        \draw [densely dashed] (1,0) node[below] {\scriptsize$ b $} -- (1,{f(1)});
        \draw [pen colour={white}, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, raise=1pt, amplitude=5pt}] (1,0) -- (1,{f(1)}) node[midway, right=5pt] {\scriptsize$ f(b) $};
        \draw [yellow, domain=0.3:0.95, samples=2] plot(\x,{g(\x)});
        \draw [yellow, densely dashed] (a,0) node[below] {\scriptsize$ \xi $} -- (a,{f(a)}) node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am actually making the lecture note in `beamer` with a black background. Please pardon the colour choices in the MWE.

Comment: What does this figure have to do with Cauchy's mean value theorem?

Comment: Maybe with a *real* function curve, it will be more relevant (and easier to find one point where the tangent slope is equal to the linear slope between a and b (if this is what you try to achieve).

Comment: @Bernard Please find the lecture note [here](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnNh_584BiIjg4hquUjod3lJJjbvyQ?e=gj8Onf). Refer to slide No. 25 and No. 30.

Comment: @SebGlav Do you mean a parametrized curve? Because the curve given there is not a graph of a function.

Comment: Precisely, you do not have the graph of a function, and all versions of the mean value theorem are about functions.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but a parametrized curve can accommodate two functions at once and can be used to explain this phenomenon of Cauchy's MVT visually.

Comment: Whatever, the graph you provided is not suitable to illustrate Lagrange MVT. I don't see the point in doing it like this.

Comment: @SebGlav I am sorry for any misunderstanding. The MWE is the drawing for Lagrange's MVT and I do not have any problems with that. The hand-drawn figure is for Cauchy's MVT. I need help with that. I included the code basically to serve as an MWE.

Comment: Sorry, I'm certainly dumb, but how a parametrized curve could be "defined" between a and b on the x axis, since x and y are defined by the parameter? I think nobody here knows how to help you without having an understandable context. Are you able to provide a prametrized curve such as the one you are talking about?

Comment: @SebGlav Please refer to the lecture note [here](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnNh_584BiIjg4hquUjod3lJJjbvyQ?e=gj8Onf) for the context. See slide nos. 25 and 30.

Comment: OK, I get it. So you have to define f and g, say f(t)=3.cos(t) and g(t)=t^3/30+t, for a nice parametric curve (I fell on finding a smart curve with the loop you drew). You draw it for t in [-1;4] and you get two points (approx with x=-3 and x=3) where the slope is the same as the rope slope. Did you try something like this? It should be possible with a `\foreach` loop and a `smooth` option for the drawing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119958/discussion-between-sebglav-and-subhajit-paul).

Comment: @SebGlav I finally settled to [this one](https://pastebin.com/raw/LsKJTLWZ). Thanks for your help! You can see the output in the shared lecture note at slide no. 30.

Comment: How is this a function at all!

Comment: @AswinPrasad, please go through the mentioned slides in the lecture note linked above.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul I mean the basic definition follows that a function values are unique.ie, for the given x there isn't two y(s). That being said I understand the definition of Cauchy's mvt based on parameterized concept. But consider this, if  Cauchy's mvt is an extension of Lagrange's. It means that it is the ratio of two lagrange mvt's for fx and gx. that is fine, but I don't understand how the point at which the slope of chord of each fx and gx are same, that is how c1=c2. I hope that I am clear with this limited characters. f(c1)/f(c2)=f(b)-f(a)/g(b)-g(a)

Comment: @AswinPrasad, please go through the mentioned slides in the lecture note linked above. Everything is worked out with diagrams and illustrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much thinking and a little help from *SebGlav*, I finally found a parametrized curve whose graph is exactly what I wanted as shown in the picture. I used portions of an outward spiral for both positive and negative values of the parameter and rotated it to get the orientation I want. I am posting my finding as an answer here. If anyone wants to edit the question to make it more searchable or the answer to make it more precise and concise, please feel free to do so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \pgfarrowsdeclaredouble{<<s}{>>s}{stealth}{stealth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-60, declare function={a=3.5; b=-a; m=0; f(\x)=\x*(sin (\x r)); g(\x)=\x*(cos(\x r));}]
            \draw [decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>>}}}, postaction={decorate}] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
            \draw [rotate=60] ({f(-a)-3},-2.5) -- ({f(b)+5},-2.5);
            \draw [smooth, domain=a:-a, samples=50, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.15 with {\arrow{>}}, mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}}}, postaction={decorate}] plot({f(\x)},{g(\x)});
            \draw [densely dashed, red, thick, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>>}}}, postaction={decorate}] ({f(a)},{g(a)-0.5}) -- ({f(b)},{g(b)+0.5});
            \draw ({f(a)},{g(a)}) node[above left] {\scriptsize$ (f(a),g(a)) $};
            \draw ({f(b)},{g(b)}) node[above left] {\scriptsize$ (f(b),g(b)) $};
            \draw (0,0) node[above=-1pt, rotate=30] {\scriptsize$ \frac{g'(\xi)}{f'(\xi)}=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{f(b)-f(a)} $};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Cauchy's MVT}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was away for a few days, but I had this:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm,y=1cm]
        \tikzset{arrowsoncurve/.style={
            decoration={markings,
                mark=at position 0.15 with {\arrow{>}},
                mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}}},
                postaction={decorate}}}
                
        \draw[line width=1pt,->] (-10,0) -- (10,0);
        \draw[line width=1pt,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
      
        \draw[line width=1pt,blue,arrowsoncurve] plot[samples=100,domain=-2.815:2.22,smooth,variable=\t] ({\t*\t*\t-4*\t+4},{\t*\t+\t-3.12});
        \draw[line width=1pt,red] plot[samples=100,domain=-10:10,smooth] (\x,0.154*\x+3.08);
        \draw[line width=1pt,red] plot[samples=100,domain=-2:10,smooth] (\x,0.154*\x-4.33);
    
        \coordinate (A) at (-7,2);
        \node [above left] at (A) {$A\left(f(a)\,,\,g(a)\right)$};
        \coordinate (B) at (6,4);
        \node [above left] at (B) {$B\left(f(b)\,,\,g(b)\right)$};
        \coordinate (M) at (6.4,-3.35);
        \node [below right] at (M) {$t \in \,]a\,,\,b[$};
        
        \path (A) -- (B) node[red,pos=0.3,above,sloped] {slope $= \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}$};
        \path (0,-4.33) -- (M) node[red,pos=0.4,below,sloped] {slope $= \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}$};
        \foreach \p in {A,B,M} \fill (\p) circle (2pt);  
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Cauchy MVT]